# password key returning false even if criteria is correct

Tags: c, if-statement, char, cs50, logical-operators

Trying to write a program that checks a password - it needs to have at least 1 uppercase, lowercase, number and punctuation but it seems to reject everything if it fit does match the criteria.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool valid(string password);

int main(void)
{
    string password = get_string("Enter your password: ");
    if (valid(password))
    {
        printf("Your password is valid!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Your password needs at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and symbol\n");
    }
}

bool valid(string password)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(password); i++)
    {
        if(isupper(password[i]) && isalnum(password[i]) && ispunct(password[i]))

        {
            return true;
        }

    }

    return false;
}
```

when I check for uppercase and numbers and punctuation individually it works - but i think there must be an issue with the if statements and using the && possibly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if statement

```
    if(isupper(password[i]) && isalnum(password[i]) && ispunct(password[i]))
```

always evaluates to false because a character can not be at the same time an alpha or a digit and a punctuation.

That is it is not enough to use only one if statement within the for loop.

I can suggest the following solution shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool valid( const char *password )
{
    enum { LowerCase = 0, UpperCase = 1, Digit = 2, Punctuation = 3 };
    static const unsigned int valid_password =
        ( 1 << LowerCase ) | ( 1 << UpperCase ) | ( 1 << Digit ) | ( 1 << Punctuation );

    unsigned int password_value = 0;

    for ( ; password_value != valid_password  && *password; ++password )
    {
        unsigned char c = *password;

        if (isalpha( c ))
        {
            password_value |= ( islower( c ) != 0 ) << LowerCase;
            password_value |= ( isupper( c ) != 0 ) << UpperCase;
        }
        else
        {
            password_value |= ( isdigit( c ) != 0 ) << Digit;
            password_value |= ( ispunct( c ) != 0 ) << Punctuation;
        }
    }

    return password_value == valid_password;
}

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "1Aa!";

    printf( "valid( \"%s\" is %s\n", s, valid( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "1Aa";

    printf( "valid( \"%s\" is %s\n", s, valid( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "Aa!";

    printf( "valid( \"%s\" is %s\n", s, valid( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "1a!";

    printf( "valid( \"%s\" is %s\n", s, valid( s ) ? "true" : "false" );

    s = "1A!";

    printf( "valid( \"%s\" is %s\n", s, valid( s ) ? "true" : "false" );
}
```

The program output is

```
valid( "1Aa!" is true
valid( "1Aa" is false
valid( "Aa!" is false
valid( "1a!" is false
valid( "1A!" is false
```

Answer (score 0):

> but it seems to reject everything if it fit does match the criteria.

A program can only do what it has been programmed to do, to the letter of the law.

> Trying to write a program that checks a password - it needs to have at
> least 1 uppercase, lowercase, number and punctuation

```
if(isupper(password[i])
   && isalnum(password[i]) 
   && ispunct(password[i]))
```

This doesn't check whether there is at least one uppercase, lowercase, digit, and punctuation in the string. This checks whether a `char` is an uppercase letter, an alphabet or digit, and a punctuation, all at the same time — which a `char` can not possibly be — and returns `true` / `false` on that basis.

---

A naive solution could be to keep some flags and iterate over the input `char` by `char`, and set them to `true` if the `ctype` functions return 0.

```
bool is_alpha = false;
bool is_upper = false;
bool is_punct = false;
bool is_digit = false;
```

Once the loop exits, we can evaluate the flags to see if the password was valid:

```
if (is_alpha && is_upper && is_punct && is_digit) {
   /* The password is valid */
} else {
   /* Handle error here */
}
```